# Java "Type parameter X is not within its bound; should implement Comparable<X>" (LocalDateTime as key in map)

Tags: java

I have implemented my own Map called AVLTreeMap. Here is the class signature.

```
public class AVLTreeMap<K extends Comparable<K>, V>
```

As you can see, I am using comparable keys in this map. The problem is that I want to instantiate a map with a `LocalDateTime` type key.

```
private AVLTreeMap<LocalDateTime, CallRecord> callRecords;
```

I am getting the error `Type parameter 'java.time.LocalDateTime' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable<java.time.LocalDateTime>'`.

As far as I can tell, LocalDateTime implements `Comparable<ChronoLocalDateTime<?>>` and at this point, I am pretty confused as to how I can create my map with a `LocalDateTime` key set.

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot check this easily right now but have you tried class AVLTreeMap<T extends Comparable<? super T>>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generic signature for a `Comparable` is a little off, this

```
public class AVLTreeMap<K extends Comparable<K>, V>
```

Should be something like

```
public class AVLTreeMap<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This definitely solved my problem. I don't have the best concept of this kind of stuff but I can already kind of see how this works. Thanks again.